# About local conjugate for a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems

Let $f:X\to X$ be a homeomorphism. We say that $p, q\in X$ are locally conjugate, if there exist open neighborhoods $U$,  $V$ of $x$  and $y$, respectively, and a homeomorphism $\gamma:U\to V$ such that $\gamma(p)=q$ and
$$\lim _{n\to \pm\infty}\sup_{z\in U}d(f^n(z), f^n(\gamma(z))))=0$$

Take $\mathcal{O}(x)= \{f^n(x)\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$.

What is the relation between $\overline{\mathcal{O}(p)}$ and $\overline{\mathcal{O}(q)}$ if $p, q\in X$ are locally conjugate.

In the following, we claim that  $\overline{\mathcal{O}(p)}=\overline{\mathcal{O}(q)}$ if $p, q\in X$ are locally conjugate. Please help me to know that it is true or not. If it is true, can we say that  if $p, q\in X$ are locally conjugate, then they are in the same orbit?

Let $y\in \overline{\mathcal{O}(p)}$. Then there is $k_n\to \infty$ with $f^{k_n}(p)\to y$, but
$\lim _{n\to \infty}d(f^{k_n}(p), f^{k_n}(\gamma(p))=0$  and $\gamma(p)=q$ implies that $f^{k_n}(q)\to y$ as $n\to \infty$. This implies that $\overline{\mathcal{O}(p)}\subseteq \overline{\mathcal{O}(q)}$

...................................................

Indeed in my research, I would like to know   that if $p$ and $q$ are locally conjugate, then what is the relation their prolongation sets? Indeed prolongation of $p$ is denoted by $D(p)$ and
$$D(p)= \bigcap \{\overline{\mathcal{O}(U)}: \text{ where $U$ is any open set of $p$ } \}$$
I think that if $p$ and $q$ are locally conjugate, then $D(p)= D(q)$. For this, assume that $y\in D(p)$, then there exist subsequence $\{k_n\}$ and $\{x_n\}\subseteq X$ with $x_n\to p$ while $f^{k_n}(x_n)\to y$. Choose $\gamma$ in definition of local conjugacy of $p, q$, hence $\gamma(x_n)\to q$ and by $\lim_{n\to\pm \infty}\sup_{z\in U}d(f^n(z), f^n(\gamma(z)))=0$, we can say that  $f^{k_n}(\gamma(x_n))\to y$, this means that $y\in D(q)$.

Please help me to know that my claim is true or not?

Comment: Your proof is incorrect: It only works for the accumulation points of orbits, not orbits themselves (and one can find examples of this  situation). Also, your definition of locally conjugate is unclear: Do you mean that either $\lim_{n\to\infty}=0$  or $\lim_{n\to-\infty}=0$ or do you mean that both limits are zero?

Comment: @MoisheKohan, Thanks, both limits are zero.

Comment: @MoisheKohan, Thanks for your interesting example. In my research, I would like to know that if $p$ and $q$ are locally conjugate, then what is the relation their prolongation sets? Indeed prolongation of $p$ denoted by $D(p)$ and $$D(p)= \cap \{\overline{\mathcal{O}(U)}: \text{ where $U$ is any open set of $p$ }\}$$

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to reflect what you are actually interested in.

Comment: I think that if $p$ and $q$ are locally conjugate, then $D(p)= D(q)$. For this, assume that $y\in D(p)$, then there exist subsequence $\{k_n\}$ and $\{x_n\}\subseteq X$ with $x_n\to p$ while $f^{k_n}(x_n)\to y$. Choose $\gamma$ in definition of local conjugacy of $p, q$, hence $\gamma(x_n)\to q$ and by $\lim_{n\to\pm \infty}\sup_{z\in U}d(f^n(z), f^n(\gamma(z)))=0$, we can say that  $f^{k_n}(\gamma(x_n))\to y$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan, I edited my question. I am so thankful if you help me

Comment: What does "open set of $p$" mean? Do you mean a neighborhood of $p$?Then prolongation will always contain the orbit itself and the same example applies.

Comment: @MoisheKohan, Yes we can used open neighborhood of $p$. Also prolongation contains the closure of orbit. About your example is it true that if $p=i$ or $-i$, then $D(p)= S^2$? Because for any open neighborhood of $p$, $U$, we have $\overline{\mathcal{O}(U)}= S^2$.

Comment: No, $D(p)$ is just $\ovevrline{O(p)}$ in my example. It is easier to see that $D(i)$ is contained in the closure of the upper half-plane and $D(-i)$ in the closure of the lower half-plane.

Comment: Did you understand the solution? If so, consider accepting it, to remove your question from the "unanswered queue."

Comment: @MoisheKohan, thanks a lot. Yes. I understand your solution. Your example was interesting and thanks for it

Comment: I understand now. You just do not believe in accepting answers in MSE as a matter of principle. I respect this, just do not think it's very productive.

Comment: @MoisheKohan, Dear, I do not know how accepting answer in MSE. Please help me to know it. Before I clicked the answer as it is useful.

Comment: I did another change. Is it OK?

Comment: I did not realize that you did not know, but now you do! Very good. Now, consider accepting answers to your other questions by other users if you find them useful! This is a polite thing to do.

Comment: @MoisheKohan. After your comment, I asked it from one of my friend. Thanks for it. With Best wishes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you proved is that the accumulation sets of the orbits ${\mathcal O}(p)$ and ${\mathcal O}(q)$ are equal. Here is an example which shows that orbits themselves need not intersect. Consider the map $f(z)=2z$ of the Riemann sphere $S^2= {\mathbb C}\cup \{\infty\}$ (put your favorite metric on the sphere, say, the one making it isometric to the unit sphere in ${\mathbb R}^3$). Take points $p=i, q=-i$ and the map $\gamma(z)=\bar{z}$. This gives a local conjugation of the points $p, q$. However, the orbits of $p, q$ are  disjoint and the accumulation sets are equal to $\{0, \infty\}$. Thus, we obtain
$$
\overline{\mathcal O}(p)\cap \overline{\mathcal O}(q)= {\mathcal O}(p)'\cap {\mathcal O}(q)',
$$
where ${\mathcal O}(z)'$ denotes the accumulation set of the orbit.

Edit. For prolongations: It is a pleasant exercise to check that in my example they are equal to the orbit closures of $i$ and $-i$ respectively. Thus, nothing new here.